# CC Validator throws error for dashboard.config file - No loaded type is marked up with a Reflector Type attribute

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Think I have messed up the config file for the dashboard.
Error - 
No loaded type is marked up with a Reflector Type attribute that matches the XML node(dashboard).
Error comes up when I validate the dashboard.config file in the CC Validator.

**This is my dashboard.config file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
<dashboard>
  <remoteServices>
    <servers>
      <!-- Update this list to include all the servers you want to connect to. NB - each server name must be unique -->
      <server name="local" url="tcp://localhost:21234/CruiseManager.rem" allowForceBuild="true" allowStartStopBuild="true" backwardsCompatible="false" />
    </servers>
      </remoteServices>
      <plugins>
        <farmPlugins>
          <farmReportFarmPlugin categories="false" />
          <cctrayDownloadPlugin />
          <administrationPlugin password="" />
        </farmPlugins>
        <serverPlugins>
          <serverReportServerPlugin />
        </serverPlugins>
        <projectPlugins>
          <projectReportProjectPlugin />
          <viewProjectStatusPlugin />
          <latestBuildReportProjectPlugin />
          <viewAllBuildsProjectPlugin />
        </projectPlugins>
        <buildPlugins>
          <buildReportBuildPlugin>
            <xslFileNames>
              <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
              <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
            </xslFileNames>
          </buildReportBuildPlugin>
          <buildLogBuildPlugin />
        </buildPlugins>
        <securityPlugins>
          <simpleSecurity />
        </securityPlugins>
      </plugins>
    </dashboard>
    </cruisecontrol>
```

Can anyone please help me on this, and also some tips on how to resolve similar issues would be helpful.

Comment: CCValidator is only useful to validate the ccnet.config. there's no validator for the dashboard.config.

Answer (score 0):

Your dashboard.config file looks a little strange, i dont think it should contain the cruisecontrol node.

I think it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dashboard>
  <remoteServices>
    <servers>
      <!-- Update this list to include all the servers you want to connect to. NB - each server name must be unique -->
      <server name="local" url="tcp://localhost:21234/CruiseManager.rem" allowForceBuild="true" allowStartStopBuild="true" backwardsCompatible="false" />
    </servers>
      </remoteServices>
      <plugins>
        <farmPlugins>
          <farmReportFarmPlugin categories="false" />
          <cctrayDownloadPlugin />
          <administrationPlugin password="" />
        </farmPlugins>
        <serverPlugins>
          <serverReportServerPlugin />
        </serverPlugins>
        <projectPlugins>
          <projectReportProjectPlugin />
          <viewProjectStatusPlugin />
          <latestBuildReportProjectPlugin />
          <viewAllBuildsProjectPlugin />
        </projectPlugins>
        <buildPlugins>
          <buildReportBuildPlugin>
            <xslFileNames>
              <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
              <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
            </xslFileNames>
          </buildReportBuildPlugin>
          <buildLogBuildPlugin />
        </buildPlugins>
        <securityPlugins>
          <simpleSecurity />
        </securityPlugins>
      </plugins>
    </dashboard>
```